# Windows App spellcheck

Tags: c#, spell-checking, winapp

I was wondering if there is another way to spell check a Windows app instead what I've been of using: "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word".  I can't buy a spell checking add-on. I also cannot use open source and would like the spell check to be dynamic..any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I have seen several similar questions, the problem is they all suggest using open source applications (which I would love) or Microsoft Word.

I am currently using Word to spell check and it slows my current application down and causes several glitches in my application. Word is not a clean solution so I'm really wanting to find some other way..  Is my only other option to recreate my app as a WPF app so I can take advantage of the [SpellCheck Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you I would download the data from the English Wiktionary and parse it to obtain a list of all English words (for instance). Then you could rather easily write at least a primitive spell-checker yourself. In fact, I use a parsed version of the English Wiktionary in my own mathematical application [AlgoSim](http://algosim.se). If you'd like, I could send you the data file.

**Update**

I have now published a parsed word list at [english.zip (942 kB, 383735 entries, zip)](http://privat.rejbrand.se/english.zip). The data originates from the English Wiktionary, and as such, is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License.

To obtain a list like this, you can either download all articles on Wiktionary as a huge XML file containing all Wiki- and HTML-formatted articles. This is then more or less trivial to parse. Alternatively, you can run a bot on the site. I got help to obtain a parsed file from a user at Wiktionary (I seem to have forgotten his name, though...), and this file (english.txt in english.zip) is a further processed version of the file I got.

Comment: That's a decent idea.. How did you obtain the data from Wiki? If I can't figure it out, I'd appreciate that file. thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.aspx

Comment: This application isn't WPF.. you can only implement the spellcheck class on textBoxes and richTextBoxes in a WPF application

Answer (score 0):

I use Aspell-win32, it's old but it's open source, and works as well or better than the Word spell check. Came here looking for a built in solution.