# delphi orthographic corrector

Tags: delphi

what´s the best component or practice  to check the orthographic  error´s in the TEdit and TRichEdit components in a Form.

Thank´s

Comment: Please also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717222/spellcheck-components-for-delphi and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723995/windows-app-spellcheck/2731250#2731250

Comment: Besides spelling errors, what additional orthographic errors do you want to check for?

Comment: +1: learned what http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthography is. --jeroen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re, do you need a Spell Checking component. check theses links

- [ExpressSpellChecker from DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Home/Announces/ExSpellChecker-v2.xml)
- [spelling check from Addictive Software](http://www.addictivesoftware.com/addict.htm#spelling)
- [Spell Checking from Delphi code using MS Word - Office Automation in Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/kbcontrolole/ss/word_automation.htm)

Comment: I´m trying Addict4 because it´s in Portuguese  . Office Automation in Delphi wouth be good but it doesent work for what i see in 2007!!!

Thank´s