# Delphi Spell Checker

Tags: delphi, spell-checking

Hi I am looking for a free spell checker to use with Delphi 7 -2010 could anyone please give me a pointer to one

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723995/windows-app-spellcheck

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spellcheck components for Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717222/spellcheck-components-for-delphi)

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand, there's exact question for Delphi, see my above comment.

Comment: The answer to the question you mentioned refers to a product you that is a paid product rather than a free one as I am asking about

Comment: I didn't vote to close because I want you to see my comment on the other questions, but because it's the same as your question here, and you read the first line only of my comment, you can see I gave LS Spell as free one,and pointed to article on Delphi.about.com for using directoies came with WinWord.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add the HunSpell library we used in our SynProject editor.
It's included in the source code of this GPL tool.
http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=SynProject
http://synopse.info/forum/viewforum.php?id=16

The .dll, and the dictionaries, are bundled to the main executable as zipped resource.
http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=314#p314