# Which spellings checker to use?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-2007, spell-checking

A customer would like it if a spellings checker is added to an existing Delphi application. The texts that need to be checked are in multiple memo fields and the language is Dutch, which tends to limit my options.
So, what are my options for adding a dutch spellings checker to a Delphi/WIN32 application?
(Preferably something not webbased because the client has no direct Internet connection.)
It doesn't have to be free! The customer will pay if it's possible. :-)
[Addictive Software](http://www.addictivesoftware.com/) offers an option, but I prefer to have more alternatives.

Comment: Duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237276/delphi-spell-checker
and this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723995/windows-app-spellcheck
and this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717222/spellcheck-components-for-delphi

Comment: Be aware: I'm asking for a DUTCH spell-checker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addictive software, as mentioned above, is one of the main ones.

But the [TRichView component](http://www.trichview.com) includes parsers for several spell-checkers that work out with Delphi. [Check out their list and links](http://www.trichview.com/features/spellcheck.html) that include:

- Addict 3 and 4 by Addictive Software (shareware VCL component)
- HunSpell by László Németh (DLL, open source)
- ExpressSpellChecker by Developer Express Inc. (commercial VCL component)
- EDSSpell 7 by OneDomain (shareware VCL component)
- ASpell by Kevin Atkinson (DLL, license: LGPL)
- VSSpell 8.0 by ComponentOne LLC (shareware ActiveX, discontinued)
- VSSpell 3.0 by Visual Components, Inc (shipped with some versions of Delphi, ActiveX)
- LS Speller by Luzius Schneider (based on former work of Alexander Obukhov) (freeware, uses ISpell and MS Office spell checkers (via CSAPI)).
- Polar SpellChecker Component by Polar (shareware ActiveX)

Comment: Very practical list of alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

I use Addict, lots of languages (including Dutch) and good support:
[AddictiveSoftware.com](http://addictivesoftware.com/products.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Jedi JVCL library has a `JvSpellChecker` component with a demo (in jvcl\examples\JvSpellChecker fodler)

Alternate option using MS Word:
**Spell Checking from Delphi code using MS Word** - Office Automation in Delphi
http://delphi.about.com/od/kbcontrolole/ss/word_automation.htm

Answer (score 1):

Hunspell is a great spell-checker, used in OpenOffice, with up-to-date dictionnaries.

See the [corresponding download at CodeCentral](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/27428).

I've implemented a self-expanding version (i.e. the library and the dictionary files are extracted from the main Delphi exe resources on request), available [as part of our SynProject FOSS application](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=314#p314).

Answer (score 1):

DevExpress Spell check is the best I have found so far, but it is not free.

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExSpellChecker/